# Form still submitting with preventDefault and return false

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using the following code to submit a form with AJAX:

```
<script>
    $('#subscribeline #subscribe').click(function(){
        $('#subscribeline').html("<form id='subscribeform'><input type='email' name='email' id='email' value='' placeholder='Enter your email'><input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='OK'></form>");
    });

    $(document).on('submit','#subscribeform', function(){ 
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : "insertsubscriber.php",
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {
                    alert('ok');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    alert('false');  
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
    });
</script>
```

Now the thing is the part of the page with this code is itself loaded with AJAX. The #subscribeform does not exist on page load so I've added the script on secondPage.php and not index.php to keep things cleaner and organized.

The whole thing works (I get an alert box with 'ok' or 'false') except it also ends up actually submitting the form despite the preventDefault and return false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing 'e'

Change this

```
$(document).on('submit','#subscribeform', function(){
```

With this

```
$(document).on('submit','#subscribeform', function(e){
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:?

```
<script>
    $('#subscribeline #subscribe').click(function(){
        $('#subscribeline').html("<form id='subscribeform'><input type='email' name='email' id='email' value='' placeholder='Enter your email'><input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='OK'></form>");
    });

    $(document).on('submit','#subscribeform', function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : "insertsubscriber.php",
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {
                    alert('ok');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    alert('false');  
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need both `return false` and `e.preventDefault()`.

Since you are not passing `e` into the `submit` handler  as @GWSMaster has mentioned, your code errors on the `e.preventDefault()` line and therefore none of the two gets executed, ending up submitting the form anyway.

Either remove `e.preventDefault()` or pass `e` into the handler and remove `return fasle;`; usually `e.preventDefault();` is the first line in the handler but it should work at any position. However, when you use `return false`, **it has to be the last line** otherwise some of your code will not be executed.